# PC randomly freezes

Tags: freeze, troubleshooting

Specs

```
Windows 7 64bit
Q6600
GTX 550 Ti
4 GB RAM
450 PSU
```

I'm fully aware this is an ancient machine and I'm working on upgrading it, an answer with: you machine is garbage and you should throw it away is not going to help me.

Basically the problem is that it just freezes for no reason sometimes.
Happens in browsing or gaming or even opening a window. It just freezes for a few second then everything is back to normal.

Now the situation is that I'm **NOT** running anything above it's ability to handle.

Like just browsing or gaming on low settings...etc yet it keeps just freezing for a few seconds. This is hell in online FPS games. For example I can push around 90 fps in a game then for a second it drops to 0 then goes up to 90. That means I just die as I froze for few seconds.

Please not I'm using gaming as an example and I know it's an old pc and that it's not going to get me triple digits frames...etc

Again this happens in even just basic browsing. So. Unless I need A core I7 with 64 GB rams to open a few pages in a browser then something wrong is going on here.

We can rule out that my OS is corrupt since it happens on different installs.
And I'm pretty sure my pc is clean since I run Kaspersky all the time.

I just changed my CPU cooler and it seems to run well. GPU seems to run well and I cleaned my PC. I'm pretty sure the PSU can handle this potato of a PC. Cables seems to be fine.

Obviously I close all other programs when I game and just keep the basic windows services and only Kaspersky and flux when I game. I check kaspersky's usage and it is nothing out of the ordinary and flux is super light. I have all unneeded services off and my startup list is only basics.

And of course I don't have other stuff working in the background like a virus scan or windows update...etc.

What even makes less since is that I tried actually running more intensive stuff together and it can run it well for a time. Like a demanding game with a demanding program. This just does not make sense. Because why would it not run 1 program smoothly but when I open 2 it does?

And for another try I lowered everything in a game to a point that a 2 times weaker PC can run it smoothly and it still froze after a while.

Even my memory usage seems to be fun. Temps also seem to be fine on both CPU and GPU.

Maybe we can argue that my problem is that my PC can't handle an intensive task successfully. Like instead of running it to the best of it's ability, like smoothly without freezing, it simply stops for a few seconds then runs it.
Again this is not running things it can't run. Since I'm pretty sure it should be able to handle browser pages.

So. I highly suspect a hardware problem but what could it be?
Is it the CPU? My motherboard?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a process manager/monitor like [Process Hacker](https://processhacker.sourceforge.io/). With it open, click the "System Information" button and it'll show you several graphs. Start using the computer and when it freezes, look at the graphs and it'll show you what resource is being used during that time. If you sort the Processses tab by I/O rate that will also help narrow down the problem.

Your specs are decent enough to run many games. The only thing that *usually* wears down in a computer is the hard drive. Its speed starts to suffer and its reliability starts going downhill after several years. I didn't see you mention having an SSD (solid state drive). That would be a cheap upgrade and increase the speed several times over. But do check the graphs I referred to earlier because that will give you a strong clue as to what the problem is. Check the Disk tab and sort by "Total rate" to narrow down disk related problems.

Comment: I use HWMonitor but ok. How will that help me? Because this happens in games or a browser. Like from Skyrim to Firefox...etc.
Yeah. No ssd. 
Lets not talk about upgrading for now though. I wanna now how to fix the problem first.

Comment: I recommended Process Hacker mainly because it shows historical data through the graphs in System Information and you can sort the processes by disk usage, memory usage, CPU usage, etc..  I'm not sure if HWMonitor does that, but if so, you should be able to use that too.  Use something to monitor the disk usage while a freeze occurs. If there is a lot of disk usage EVERY TIME it freezes, the hard drive may not be able to keep up with the amount of activity that is occurring, thus leading to a freeze to occur.  Confirm that high disk activity is occurring every time a freeze occurs. continued..

Comment: If a freeze occurs and there is not high disk usage, then it's probably not that. Hard drive is my preliminary guess as to the cause because it's the only thing that (1) wears out over time, and (2) your other components should be able to handle everything. I do recommend upgrading to an SSD because it will improve nearly everything you do on the computer from boot times to loading applications.  Also meant to ask you, if you restart your computer and then immediately open a game and start playing, how many minutes afterwards does a freeze occur? continued..

Comment: Or can the computer be going for hours without a freeze? In Process Hacker you can sort by Disk rate, Memory usage, CPU usage. Basically just watch what process is using the highest amount of each during the time it freezes and investigate from there. If the highest disk usage process is the application that the freeze occurs in, then it's probably related to disk speed. If the highest memory usage process is the application that the freeze occurs in, then it's probably related to memory, etc.

Comment: You can use something like [CrystalDiskMark](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskmark/) to benchmark your hard drives. To give you a speed comparison, I just purchased my SSD drive a few months ago and [here it my benchmark](https://i.imgur.com/L3B35Pq.png).

Comment: I thought getting an ssd might fix it but it's still the same shit. I did not get any better fps in game and I still get fps drops down to zero. What is there to be done?. Sorry it took me so long I was just waiting for my ssd to figure out if it fixes it or not

Comment: Can you use Speccy and then File -> Publish Snapshot... that way I can see your system specs and can make a better determination what's going on.

Comment: Alright. 
http://speccy.piriform.com/results/cMchvEiuVLJAB0pLI7UBC8D .

I plan on buying new mobo+CPU+RAM next month but worried that it might be my PSU which might mean destroying the new stuff. So just get a PSU? Won't have money for the rest and will have to wait for a couple of month with this PoS pc. My PSU is powerstation 2 450W 80 plus one. If you could help me figure out what's wrong it would be great. I can just throw or fix the faulty part

Comment: How long has Windows been installed? After Windows has been running for 3-4+ years, it slows down due to junk/build up in the system after updates and installing/uninstalling programs. You might try installing Windows from scratch. But if you're getting a new mobo+CPU+RAM in a month, wait until then. A CPU won't affect the speed, only if it restarts or dies randomly is it the PSU.  I cannot see your CPU, motherboard, or RAM in that Speccy URL, it just says "bad allocation".

Comment: I installed it 15 days ago. I installed it on the SSD thinking maybe my old HDD is the problem. Anyway boat time is insane. Like 1 minute and we are already. 
Now my biggest concern now is the PSU since it's the piece I will be using. You said if it's crashing randomly it's the PSU. I don't crash or restart or get BSoD. Just the 1-5 second freezing then back to normal. So. What can be done to make sure my PSU won't hurt the new stuff? I won't mind going to a shop and asking for a test but I wanna know what to ask for. I'm good with software but not hardware...

Comment: Yeah. I closed speccy, ran it again, and still got the same result. Is there another program or another method or what to do?
Btw thanks for taking from your time to try to help me

Comment: Message me on Telegram and we'll chat!  https://t.me/asheroto

Comment: Really sorry but it's not working now for some reason. 
Do you like use facebook?

Answer (score 1):

May be you should park you cores with [ParkControl](https://bitsum.com/parkcontrol/) software. Or at least check the version that freezes can be caused by incorrect operation of one of the cores (or switching a core from passive to active mode when the load on the CPU increases).

Comment: Is there a guide for that program? I'm worried I'd mess something up

Comment: Tried it. Does not do much I'm afraid